# Frequency analysis of discrete time series

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I guess this will be simple question for someone knowing any math... 
Anyway, I am researching some electronic noise sampling technique from one paper, and one part that gives me headache is as follows:

I am sampling the random noise signal with some frequency f0 (in Hz), and I get time series of sampled values (integers):
Z(t) = {... 34, 567, 1241, 35, 678...}
The paper then describes that in order to analyse frequencies in that signal, I should calculate the alteration speeds (derivation) in each time instant, using plain formula:
Z(t) - Z(t-1)
And it just says that these alteration speed can be interpreted as frequencies, thus new frequency sequence arises for each time instant (disregard the actual values, I made them up here):
f(t) = {... 1000 Hz, 867 Hz, 1200 Hz, ...}

Is there any idea here how these alteration speed can be seen as frequencies?

Regards,
Toni

Answer (score 0):

After calculating the set of frequencies, you can set some centers and put those frequency values in neighborhood of each center in a group represented by the center frequency. Now each group has some members. So you can compare the frequencies appeared in the noise sequence by comparing number of members of each group.